how to use a Persistent NFS Volume to store log files of postgresql
I have postGresql db running in the redhat system. the database data and logs file are in the local server.
we start the DB service using the command
  /usr/pgsql-15/bin/pg_ctl -D /apac-info-sb/pgsql/data -l /apac-info-sb/pgsql/logfile start

there have some logs like "checkpoint, select" information  in the log files of /apac-info-sb/pgsql/data/log (for example :postgresql-Sun.log)
but i found there is a NFS driver to store more detail logs of postGresql like , for example : postgresql-Sun.log
2024-08-04 23:55:59.978 EDT [63708] LOG:  process 63708 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on tuple (1843648,21) of relation 18279 of database 16387 after 1000.098 ms

  2024-08-04 23:56:03.039 EDT [60390] STATEMENT:  SELECT AH_Idnr FROM AH WHERE AH_Idnr=$1 FOR UPDATE
2024-08-04 23:57:00.005 EDT [3121019] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "svc_postperf"
2024-08-04 23:57:00.005 EDT [3121019] DETAIL:  Role "svc_postperf" does not exist.
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 87: "host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0           md5"

the NFS driver is mounted from a remote server. i just want to know which application generated those logs, how to set the folder to be output logs.
Thanks
